# i want using dettach single row, with this case

Tags: laravel, controller

I have 3 tables.

1. table worker
2. table attendance
3. table attendance_worker

in `attendance_worker` look like this

```
id | worker_id | attendance_id | info
 1       2             1        present
 2       3             1        present
 3       2             2        present
 4       3             2        absent
```

i want delete `worker_id=3` with `attendance_id=1`

what should I do in my controller to detach that single row? I'm really bad for logic, I'm a newbie here to learn larval

**This is my controller**

```
public function deleteattendance($id)
{
    $data= Attendance::find($id);
    $data->Worker()->detach();
    return redirect('attendance/detail/'.$id);
}
```

this is a screenshot for my blade

[image: attendance]

Comment: Hey, I think the main thing you are missing here, is the second id that you need to identify the correct record. Your detach should look something like `$data->Worker()->detach(3);` (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

Comment: yah i know if i add `->dettach(3)` it will be delete data worker_id=3 with attendance_id=1. but if my case i want do with a button delete. i really bad to make variabel, bytheway thanks for respon.

Comment: you have to send ```worker_id``` to your controller and then call ```$data->Worker()->detach($worker_id);```

Comment: So to be sure I understand you correctly: You know adding `3` will work, but you don't know where you should get the value `3` from(as in no variable contains it)?

Comment: What @Babak sais is true. You can send the data via get/post or even include it in the route like `Route::delete('worker/{worked_id}/attendance/{attendance_id}', 'Yourcontroller@somefunction')` this way your `$request` will allways have access to both worker and attendance_id

Comment: yes thats i mean, im sorry, i just learn with following tutorial youtube but now i make other case..

Comment: how to make specific row delete . i already make it variabel like this


`public function deleteattendance($id)
    {
        $worker_id = Attendance_worker::find($id);
        $data= Attendance::find($id);
        $data->Worker()->detach($worker_id);
        return redirect('attendance/detail/'.$id);
    }`

it will delete with attendance_id = 1 
i need that '$id' in funcition deleteattendance($id) for show my spesific date for attendance.

Comment: Or! @RobBiermann you can define your route just like this : Route::delete('/{worker_id}/{attendance_id}') ; and you will get exactly like your route. but you will hide some info from people.

Comment: how to write code in comment?  using 
`
code
`

Comment: @Sorooshn IMHO I don't like a route like that, as it is not explicit and does collide with other routes too much + what info does it hide exactly?

Comment: With your routing system , hackers for example will know what value is on your url and they can plan easier for any kind of attack. Totally I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your form :

```
<table class="table table-hover table-in-card">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">No</th>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Info</th>
    <th scope="col" class="">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($attendance->worker as $key->$worker)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $key+1 }}</th>
        <td>{{$worker->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$worker->pivot->info}}</td>
        <td>
            <form  method="post" action="{{route('worker.delAttend',['worker'=>$worker->id,'attend'=>$attend->id])}}">
                @method('DELETE')
                @csrf
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Your route :

```
Route::delete('/d/{worker}/{attend}',[Controller::class,'deleteattendance'])->name('worker.delAttend');
```

Your controller :

```
public function deleteattendance(WorkerModel $worker, AttendModel $attend){
    $attend->Worker()->detach($worker['id']);
    return redirect('attendance/detail/'.$id);
}
```

Let me know if there is any problem!

Comment: i getting error before i get the form delete.

![image](https://i.imgur.com/AFZk66k.png)

i do like your suggestion

Comment: this is not about my code. This is about your attendance/detail/id route! There is no such an id in your redirecting route. @user14521540

Comment: sir it still not work sir.. i dont know to solve it help me

Comment: Sir , I updated my answer a little according with your form. check it please. and about your problem, just tell me your error. If you still have your last error , give me your routes. let me see your routes. I dont even know what is your error exactly. my telegram id is sn_tel. If you want to connect me , just post me your problem there. I will try my best to answer u.

Comment: sir i still try with your suggestion, but still error, i try contac you to your Telegram, but my accout Telegram hasn't been used for a long time, it need to recovery account and need 2x24 hours , maybe you have something like telegram like as Discord maybe or something like else, by theway this is my Telegram @mj_jule (meglo_jule)

Comment: i already contac you sir in telegram, and i already too update your request about my route, and error. i send screenshoot error in your telegram sir.. thank you sir..

Answer (score 0):

```
</div>
            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                Add Attendace Worker
              </button>
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-in-card">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">No</th>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">Info</th>
                                <th scope="col" class="">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php $i=1;?>
                            @foreach($attendance->worker as $key->$worker)
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{ $i }}</th>
                                <td>{{$worker->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$worker->pivot->info}}</td>
                                <td>
<form  method="post" action="{{route('worker.delAttend',['worker'=>$worker->id,'attend'=>$attend->id])}}">
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        @csrf
                                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $i++;?>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <label> Present : {{$attendance_worker_present}}</label><br>
        <label> Absent : {{$attendance_worker_absent}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

all my route attendance

```
    Route::get('/attendance', 'AttendancesController@index')->name('attendance');
    Route::get('/attendance/create', 'AttendancesController@create');
    Route::post('/attendance/store', 'AttendancesController@store');
    Route::get('/attendance/{attendance}/show', 'AttendancesController@show');
    Route::post('/attendance/{attendance}/adddate', 'AttendancesController@adddate');
    Route::delete('/{worker}/{attend}',[Attendance::class,'deleteattendance'])->name('worker.delAttend');
```

my controller

```
    public function deleteattendance(WorkerModel $worker, AttendModel $attend){
        $attend->Worker()->detach($worker['id']);
        return redirect('attendance/detail/'.$id);
    }
```